# Manually selecting content for a view

Tags: views

is it possible to manually select content for a view? I'd like to create a *related content* view but I want to add the links manually for every article, not using taxonomy.

Is it possible? Is their a certain module that exists?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use References module (https://drupal.org/project/references) and create Node Reference field, which will allow multiple values.

Steps:

- Create the node reference field
- Add Node:nid to the views contextual filters to know which node you are on
- Add related content field to the views Relationships to filter out the correct related nodes

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. Right now I only have the article title showing, is their a way to have the image used in the article show as well

Comment: Yes, just add the image field under Fields, and make it use the created relationship with the related node.